# Blob video via createObjectURL does not work

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm trying to make a HTML file where I can either upload a local video file, or put a link to a video file, and have it embedded in the HTML. Problem is, uploading a video file results in a blob video that's completely empty: 0:00 duration; completely grayed out.

I've checked that the embedding is not the problem (I went to the blob:null link itself and it doesn't work) and that the video file is not the problem (put the path to the file in the text bar and it worked) so the problem seems to be the createObjectURL function. The video file is an .mp4 file if you're curious.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var new_embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
      new_embed.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
      alert(URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
      new_embed.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height: 100%;");
      document.getElementById("player-theater-container").appendChild(new_embed);
          var butte = document.getElementById("inputer");
          butte.remove();
          butte = document.getElementById("texbax");
          butte.remove();
      }
  });

  document.getElementById("texbax").addEventListener('change', function() {
      var new_embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
      new_embed.setAttribute("src", this.value);
      new_embed.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height: 100%;");
      document.getElementById("player-theater-container").appendChild(new_embed);
          var butte = document.getElementById("inputer");
          butte.remove();
          butte = document.getElementById("texbax");
          butte.remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a Firefox bug, this code works fine in Chrome, and should work in FF too:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var new_embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
      new_embed.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
      new_embed.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height: 100%;");
      document.getElementById("player-theater-container").appendChild(new_embed);
      var butte = document.getElementById("inputer");
      butte.remove();
      butte = document.getElementById("texbax");
      butte.remove();
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("texbax").addEventListener('change', function() {
    var new_embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
    new_embed.setAttribute("src", this.value);
    new_embed.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height: 100%;");
    document.getElementById("player-theater-container").appendChild(new_embed);
    var butte = document.getElementById("inputer");
    butte.remove();
    butte = document.getElementById("texbax");
    butte.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="texbax">
<input type="file" id="inputer">
<div id="player-theater-container"></div>
```

But there is no reason to use an <embed> element here, simply go with a [<video>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) which will get the job done everywhere.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const file = this.files[0];
  const url = URL.createObjectURL( file );
  loadVideo( url );
});

document.getElementById("texbax").addEventListener('change', function() {
    const url = this.value;
    loadVideo( url );
});

function loadVideo( url ) {
  const new_vid = document.createElement("video");
  new_vid.src = url;
  new_vid.controls = true;
  new_vid.style.cssText = "width:100%; height: 100%;";
  document.getElementById("player-theater-container").appendChild(new_vid);
  document.getElementById("inputer").remove();
  document.getElementById("texbax").remove();
}
```

```html
<input id="texbax">
<input type="file" id="inputer">
<div id="player-theater-container"></div>
```

Comment: I actually use Google Chrome instead of Firefox.